# How to export the excel file with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, maatwebsite-excel

I've tried maatwebsite to excel export data from the database but once downloaded, the file cannot be opened ,

```
    $users = user::select('username', 'email')->get();
 // work on the export
      Excel::create('users', function($excel) use ($users){
         $excel->sheet('sheet 1', function($sheet) use ($users)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($users);
            });
        })->download('xlsx');
```

When the file is open :

[image]

please help me :(

Note:
I've added:

> Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,
>
> 'Excel'     => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,

Comment: $users is not Array. Thats the problem.

Comment: From the `->get()` method add `->toArray()`. Done.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work :(

Comment: my references. -> http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-import-export-to-excel-and-csv-using-maatwebsite-exampleexample.html